# vsftp user created files cannot be read by apache2

Tags: permissions, apache2, vsftpd

I have a Ubuntu 11.10 server setup with rackspace. Pretty basic setup LAMP, vsftp.

Create a new user for vsftp that can create files on the server perfectly fine.

But the files seem to be -rw------- when this user creates them, I'd like to see more of a -rw-r--r-- so that the files (.php files) can be served by Apache.

Where do I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the 'local_umask' option in vsftpd.conf (its default value is '077' IIRC, which you might want to change to '033' or '022').